# Virtual memory without an MMU

Tags: memory

Is virtual memory possible without an MMU? Can a kernel be written to create software-based virtual memory? If none of this is possible, why is that so?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by virtual memory, and what is it you are trying to achieve? Is this a piece of homework? Are you trying to run existing binary programs, say Windows binaries? Is the goal to run many programs which are too large to fit physical memory? Is the goal only to protect programs from each other (which doesn't need virtual memory)? Are the programs malicious or might they only be defective? Could all programs be recompiled from high-level language source code? Is this for any type of CPU? Which technologies have you loked at, e.g. NaCl?

Comment: Further, what scale of overhead or performance penalty are you willing to accept? What constraints are acceptable? As it stands this question seems too broad and vague to answer with anything more specific than: "Yes, it is possible."

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly *possible*, but you may have to redefine what "memory" is.

To make this transparent to a task or process, you will most likely have to emulate *every* operation, essentially creating a rather slow virtual machine. The kernel (virtual machine manager) can then verify each call and return data from either RAM or disk, or prevent illegal access.

A more cooperative design can be used, but it is more intrusive. Each task or process can *request* to use a certain block of memory, and promise not to touch it before and after the request has been granted/released. This can not detect an illegal access, but it can allow a number of tasks to run in a limited memory space, assuming the kernel can manually copy the memory somewhere when it is not currently needed by a task. Memory can be copied to and from disk during a context switch, if necessary.

Neither of these are really practical, of course. To answer the question about why it is not possible, just remember that without an MMU, one task can overwrite any memory, and the kernel has no idea where a task has been writing or where it is going to read.

Comment: I thought a kernel has total control over processes.

Comment: @Melab Not without an MMU. It's the MMU that makes it possible for a kernel to intercept and limit what a process does.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Something must be missing from our conversation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write a piece of software which emulates a CPU with an MMU, and use that to execute programs. AFAIK, modern CPUs will have such an emulator built by the CPU manufacturer. I believe some emulators are available as commercial products.

You would write your OS to use the emulated hardware, and run existing binary programs. This might be quite slow, I [SWAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess) 5-50x slower.

A system which may give better performance doesn't emulate every instruction in software, but instead translates binary program instructions for the emulated CPU to the actual machine, once or as needed. This can give significantly higher performance.

An example, which has other capabilities too, is [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) with a helpful explanation at [Wikipedia QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU)

If the goal is only to protect program from each other (and not run programs which don't fit into RAM), then there are approaches which translates binary programs into 'safe' binary programs which execute 'safely' on the same hardware as the original binary program was targeted. An example of that is [Google's Native Client (aka NaCl)](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client). If you are interested in trying it, there are specially built versions of Chrome which have the ability to run multiple binary program within Chrome using NaCl.

If it is acceptable to restrict the set of programs to ones where the source code is available, there may be more options.

Though they aren't designed for the general task of implementing Virtual memory, other examples of running programs which are mutually protected are demonstrated in the Java Virtual Machine and the .NET virtual machine. The early implementations were interpreters, interpreting every instruction afresh. Then they popularised 'Just-In-Time' (JIT) compilation. JIT gave massive performance improvements in certain common cases, based on the 80/20 rule; more than 80% of the runtime is spent in less than 20% of the code. So the overhead of translation is offset by the much higher performance of translated instructions.

Concretely, you might be able to optimise, for example by never evicting data memory, only program memory. That might allow the system to translate emulated instructions into safe real data access instructions, while checking every function call for an emulated page-out.

All of these techniques sacrifice performance, and some may only apply to subsets of Virtual Memory behaviour. It all depends on how much overhead you are willing to pay, or which other constraints you are able to accept.